# Dynamic PHP pages with unconventional URLs indexed by Google?

Tags: html, url

I've recently designed a webpage and am trying to get each individual page referenced on google. Problem is, I dont really have any actual pages on my website (that sounds silly, I know).
Here is the website: [Can of Clouds](http://canofclouds.com/thought/) if you could take a quick look.

A random hash key is put on the end of the url when the user loads the page. Then, using an ajax call, the question for this key is loaded from the database into the box. So what I'm trying to do is get every page (e.g. .../thought/#1, .../thought/#2, .../thought/#3, ...) indexed on Google. First step I would think would be creating a perma-link to each question. Is this what I should do? If so, what would be the best way? If not, what would be the easiest way of getting each individual question indexed by Google.

Thanks, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started Google is your friend, in more than one way.

Comment: Thanks Piskvor! Add it as an answer so I can accept it!